# Can't Find Documentation for HTTPd Directory Directive

Tags: apache-2.2, configuration, documentation

I've been searching through the httpd docs and google, and I simply cannot find ANYWHERE that documents ***the complete list of what may go inside of the Directory directive***.

Here's the main documentation of the Directory directive: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#directory.  It talks about what the directive DOES, but not what it can CONTAIN.  At the end, it links to a page called [How <Directory>, <Location>, and <Files>](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/sections.html) sections work, which ALSO does not have the documentation I'm looking for.

I have googled for:

- [httpd Directory directive](https://www.google.com/search?q=httpd%20Directory%20directive)
- [httpd Directory configuration](https://www.google.com/search?q=httpd+Directory+directive)
- [httpd Directory contents](https://www.google.com/search?q=httpd+Directory+contents)
- [httpd Directory directive configuration](https://www.google.com/search?q=httpd+Directory+directive+configuration)
- [all httpd Directory options](https://www.google.com/search?q=all+httpd+Directory+options)

Comment: Why do you want to know this?

Comment: So that I can correctly configure my httpd server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use whatever is flagged with a `d` here:

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/quickreference.html

For the rest, that's just how the docs are organized.

Comment: That's awful, but I guess there's no better way when options are shared across directives.  Thanks for finding this - it'll be a good start, and it does technically provide the information I'm looking for.